# How do I avoid 'No GPS signal' in Pokemon Go on an iPad with a GPS?

Tags: pokemon-go

My iPad does have a GPS, and it's active, but I'm still getting the message:

> GPS signal not found

The game makes it hard by not requesting for access. Is there a way to stop this message?

Comment: @Dragonrage Wifi-only iPads do not have GPS. Mobile/Cellular enabled ones do.

Comment: @Robotnik ah, I did not know that. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: I'm new to this site XD

Comment: @user155445 welcome to Arqade :). I have added the info from the comments into your question for you. If you can add anything else to it, please do :)

Comment: Reopening because as I've covered above: some models of iPad (including the OP's) do in fact have a GPS and thus is not the same issue as the iPod in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your GPS is on.
- Make sure you have a signal.
- Bad weather can affect this.

If you are still getting the error, reset the app, wait a while (5-10 mins) then try again.

Note: this does happen regularly while the app is opening. Give it a minute to pick up the signal.

Sometimes if you haven't allowed access to certain functions (i.e. GPS) you can turn this on in your [settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/211623/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-your-iphone-or-ipad/):

- Open Settings
- Find the "Pokémon Go" app
- Find the "GPS" or "Location" setting, and make sure it is on/allowed

Comment: I tried still not working

Answer (score 1):

Whilst @Ben's answer is correct for iPads that have a mobile/cellular data connection, note that if your iPad is a **Wi-Fi-only** model, then you do not have a GPS chip:

> WiFi-only iPad models (ones without cellular network capability) do NOT have a built-in GPS.
>   <sub>[Source](http://kb.hemamaps.com.au/article/AA-00312/0/Apps-iOS-Which-iPad-models-have-GPS-built-in.html)</sub>

You **may** have some luck [using an external Bluetooth GPS receiver](http://www.howtogeek.com/70134/how-to-use-an-external-gps-device-with-your-ipad-or-iphone/), however Pokemon Go **also** requires a network connection, so you will also need to utilise Wi-Fi hotspots or tethering in order to get Pokemon Go to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While using my iPad, whenever the message popped up, I just swipe up and turn my Bluetooth off for a few seconds and then turn it back on, suddenly my trainer starts to walk and let's me capture the Pokemon next to me, but it only lasts a few seconds so you'll have to click on the pokemon right away